# What does the "dynamic" attribute mean on a "span" element?

Tags: html

I have come across the following tag, and am really curious as to what the `dynamic` attribute means. Google is not being very helpful, as it returns most results for dynamic attributes and dynamically adding attributes, not for this attribute itself.

So, what effect does the `dynamic` attribute have on `span`, and possibly other, elements?

Comment: Where have you come across it? It doesn't appear in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "dynamic" attribute according to the standard.  However, it has always been possible to add arbitrary attributes to elements for various reasons and I guess this is one of those cases.  HTML5 defines a standard way to add "dynamic" and/or "custom made" attributes to elements, that's by prefixing the attribute with "data-".  If you do that, you can have your own "data" attributes but still validate your document according to the HTML5 standard.

Comment: Yes, I understand full well the dynamic - or custom - attributes with a `data-` prefix, hence my frustration because that is all Google could muster.

Comment: Guess that's just because "dynamic" is such a generic term and generally just refers to dynamic/custom attributes.  Like I said before, there is no "dynamic" attribute per se :-)